# How good idea it is to use object prototypes as default values?

Tags: javascript

Things like `Array.prototype`, `Function.prototype` all return empty functions, and are already created and built-in, so how good an idea it is to use them as default values, as in:

```
function isThisCool(vals,fn,rx) {
  vals = vals || Array.prototype;
  fn = fn || Function.prototype;
  rx = rx || RegExp.prototype;
}
```

The obvious advantage over using empty literals is that these are created only once and empty literals are created every time.

Comment: Using the same object (prototype or global variable) will only work if you do not modify it. Otherwise your function will behave differently every time.

Answer (score 1):

I think one thing you have to worry about with this approach is the fact that you may end up extending native prototypes which is usually considered bad practice. In your example:

```
function isThisCool(vals) {
  vals = vals || Array.prototype;
}
```

If you did something like `vals.foo = 5;`, every single array you create after this would now have a `foo` property of `5`, as you can see here:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr.foo; // => 5
```

Of course, it wouldn't really make sense to add a property to an array, but this is just an example.

If you did it the normal way:

```
function isThisCool(vals) {
  vals = vals || [];
}
```

You would not have the issue of `Array.prototype` being extended if you did `vals.foo = 5;`:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr.foo; // => undefined
```

If you don't plan on extending any of these prototypes, it probably wouldn't be an issue though.

Comment: Well, assigning random properties to any `Array` object is considered bad practice, as they do not preserve over copying array operations, such as `filter` or `map`.

Comment: "Of course, it wouldn't really make sense to add a property to an array, but this is just an example". I'm aware that it's bad practice, but @daremkd originally said that he might consider modifying some of these values.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that using these as default values can, in general, lead to accidental **modification** of those prototypes. Because as you said, these are created just once. This is effect of calling `Array.prototype.push` repetitively:

```
console.log("Push returns: ", Array.prototype.push("dd"));
```

[image: image description]

This also affects other arrays. Although they will report `length` correctly, the values will be accessible:

```
Array.prototype.push("dd");
var empty = [];
console.log(empty.length, empty[0]);
```

[image: image description]

You **could** use the prototypes for **read-only** operations. I do not recommend it. If you're woried about performance, at least create your own static default values:

```
 var default_array = [];
 var default_function = function(){};
 var default_regexp = new RegExp("");
```

Also, regarding `RegExp`, it's quite questionable how the default value should behave. Should default `RegExp` always match or always fail?

Comment: Regarding your comment "though they will report length correctly, the values will be accessible"... The entries are resolved first in the array and then up in the prototype chain. In your case empty.length is 0 and empty[0] is resolved in the prototype where there is a value for the index 0.

Comment: I know, I don't remember wondering about that. The `length` value remains correct because it's a getter.

Comment: I wanted to clarify. And... no it's not because *length* is a getter, it's because of the context (in the prototypical chain) where it is resolved: the "empty" array object in your case.

Comment: @AlexPollan I see, you're right - `[].hasOwnProperty("length")` returns true.

Answer (score 0):

I think is not a good idea at all. I can see many reasons:

- unreadable code
- unintended usage of language characteristics
- error prone (reference)

For instance, if you later do:

```
vals.push(aValue);
```

you actually are modifying the "shared" array. Every array initialized from the *Array.prototype* will be affected.

Comment: Although it does not actually affect the arrays (they won't share the length).